# How to remove .exe file created by Pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

First time posting question here. I used Pyinstaller 3.1 to create an executable file of a .py file.

How do I remove the executable file? Do I just manually delete the build folder, dist folder and .spec file located in c:\python35\scripts?

Is there a proper way?

Thanks so much for answering!

Comment: Huh? Yeah, just delete the files. The program wasn't "installed" in any real way (e.g. registry values).

Comment: Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Just remove them manually. The "proper way" I guess could be using a terminal, which you could do by running:

```
rmdir /s /q build | rmdir /s /q dist | rm <file_name>.spec
```